# WPF Storyboard animation isn't fluid

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Make control1 Visible, make control2 Collapsed, animate opacity from 1 to 0 on control 1 over .8 seconds.

immediately after that is done, do this:

Make control1 Collapsed, make control2 Visible, animate opacity from 0 to 1 on control2 over .8 seconds.

I just can't get it to be fluid and I'm out ideas. here's what I have:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sb">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.8000000" Storyboard.TargetName="MainTabControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.8000000" Storyboard.TargetName="MainTabControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.8000000" Duration="00:00:00.8000000" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchProjectsView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.8000000" Duration="00:00:00.8000000" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchProjectsView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000" Value="0"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Is it possible to post all of the code or a zip of the sample projects so that it's easy for us to run it and help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question why you would animate the Opacity and Visbility at the same time, but your problem is that the animation of the Visibility of the second control should start immediately, not after 0.8 seconds.

This should work:

```
<Storyboard>

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Storyboard.TargetName="MainTabControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Storyboard.TargetName="SearchProjectsView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="MainTabControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.8"/>

    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="SearchProjectsView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="0" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:0.8" Duration="0:0:0.8"/>

</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Because if a controls opacity is 0, its still is being drawn on the window. It might be completely transparent but blocking fully visible elements under it.

Comment: I thought hit testing in WPF ignores transparent pixels.

Comment: @BradleyUffner No, it doesn't ignore them. It only ignores `null` background fill brushes.